# Some information about this programmer

Tags: bios

I have bought this [USB programmer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/CH341A-Programmer-Modulo-programmatore-adattatore/dp/B08TVNPTQK).

I want to flash this chip: [GD25Q64](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CBNCWVD3)

For the motherboard ASUS A88XM-E (flash with coreboot image).

One quick question: I have read somewhere the black programmer uses 5V (the blue version 3.5V only), and the ROM can support 3.5V max. Do I risk burning something?
Is it better to extract the firmware chip from the socket using pliers or using the "clothes-pin" of the kit?

Comment: The linked information was not in English (required for this site).  For voltage, do not over volt the chip. You can possibly ruin any chip this way.  If you wish to remove the chip (and it is removable), use a proper IC remover.  I do this to remove ICs

Comment: I have correct the links, now are in english

Comment: The picture of the chip is a surface mount chip.  You need special equipment to remove it

Comment: Coreboot docs report GD25Q64, so I bought a GD25Q64, and also report "Socketed" https://github.com/coreboot/coreboot/blob/main/Documentation/mainboard/asus/a88xm-e.md

Comment: Well the screenshot you provided doesn’t show a socketed chip. “Do I risk burning something?” - Yes

Comment: Thanks for answer, I already search and found an usb programmer with 3.3v mod

Comment: For the bios this one is ok? https://imgur.com/RrRkbN2.png

Comment: My gut feeling tells me that if you need to ask then probably you shouldn't be doing it?